# Excel file to Html using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Tags: laravel

I just setting up Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel plugin from here https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/. I want to read excel file and display data in Html table in a blade In laravel. I got datas by using following:

```
$content=Excel::load($file, function($reader) {

})->get();
```

when I echo $content; I have following ::

```
SheetCollection {#762 ▼
  #title: ""
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => RowCollection {#623 ▼
      #title: "Sheet1"
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => CellCollection {#693 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Abc"
            "city" => "City1"
          ]
        }
        1 => CellCollection {#692 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Xyz"
            "city" => "city2"
          ]
        }
        2 => CellCollection {#710 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Name2"
            "city" => "city3"
          ]
        }
        3 => CellCollection {#709 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Name2"
            "city" => "city3"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    1 => RowCollection {#728 ▼
      #title: "Sheet2"
      #items: []
    }
    2 => RowCollection {#697 ▼
      #title: "Sheet3"
      #items: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Those are data on my xlsx file . Now I want to render it on view blade . any Idea???? thanks

Comment: Have you checked http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/blade#load-view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) methods to get data. Explore the methods but I think you can try something like this.

```
return $content->all();
```

or iterate each row and store them formated in your data to render it in a blade view using each.

```
$content->each(function($row){
   // process here each row
});
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Using this am unable to get head of excelsheet